# how to page left and page right on a line in notepad++ and vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

I am viewing some files in VScode and notepad++ and do not like to wrap my lines.

some of the files have lines > 1k characters.

Is there a way to page right/left, as there is in excel (`alt` + `pgdn`)?

Comment: related for the VS Code part of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76627334/11107541

Comment: thanks for the vs link - `shft` + `alt` + mousepad works