# How can I quickly scroll horizontally in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

For vertical scrolling, I am used to using page up and page down keyboard keys. I also know that I can hold <kbd>alt</kbd> to scroll quickly vertically with the scrollwheel / touchpad. Are there analogous actions for scrolling horizontally quickly in VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, at the time of this writing, there is no keyboard shortcut command in VS Code for scrolling horizontally by pages, but you can hack a shoddy solution by just using [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) and binding keyboard shortcuts to invoke the horizontal scroll commands multiple times. Ex.

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+left",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["scrollLeft","scrollLeft","scrollLeft","scrollLeft","scrollLeft"],
    },
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["scrollRight","scrollRight","scrollRight","scrollRight","scrollRight"],
    },
},
```

If you like history, the feature-request that got the horizontal scrolling commands added was [Add keyboard shortcuts for scrolling horizontally
#143466](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143466).

As for the scrollwheel and touchpad, the same <kbd>alt</kbd> feature should work for horizontal scrolling (which is done by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>), so you'd hold <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> while scrolling.